# SELECT DISTINCT combination of distinct values, plus non-distinct values?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am having a lot of trouble finding any documentation on executing a simple MySQL query that will return all distinct values from a combination, but also return another column that is not distinct.

In my case `report, topic, lat, lng, event` must be the distinct combination of values, but I also want to return the `docID` column.

If I include `docID` as a distinct value, it returns every document, because each `docID` is unique.

`SELECT distinct
 report, topic, lat, lng, event, /*and each of their*/ docID FROM reports`

I know this question is really simple, but I just can't find any documentation about it.

Comment: Seems possible I suppose, but it strikes me odd that there is no built in mechanism for dealing with this.

Comment: Then you should decide if you really need to use DISTINCT, if you want the `docID` column, then it will need to get all values in that column, unless you want the MINinum or MAXimum, or some other aggregate on the `docID` column.

Comment: Thanks everybody, I guess I just couldn't get out of the wrong mindset.

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT report, topic, lat, lng, event, 
group_concat(docID) as ids 
FROM reports
group by report, topic, lat, lng, event
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using GROUP BY:

```
SELECT report, topic, lat, lng, event, docID
FROM reports
GROUP BY report, topic, lat, lng, event
```

But be aware that if a docID is duplicated among a particular grouping, only one value will show up.

Answer (score 1):

The logic can give you your answer.

If several docs has the same combination of (report, topic, lat, lng, event), then which docId would you want to see of them ?

If you want all of them then you don't want a real distinct.

If you want only one (or a concat, or any operation), then MySQL cannot choose it arbitrarily for you, you have to query it (MIN, MAX, FIRST, GROUP_CONCAT, ...).

Then the reply is : you must use a GROUP clause. Like :

```
SELECT report, topic, lat, lng, event, MIN(docId) AS docIdMin 
FROM my_table
GROUP BY report, topic, lat, lng, event
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select report, topic, lat, lng, event, max(docID)
From reports
group by report, topic, lat, lng, event
```

Checkout the Group By http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_max

Answer (score 0):

I find I solve this with a group by and a `Max` or `Min` because for each distinct line there may be several `DocId` values.

```
SELECT report, topic, lat, lng, event, Max(docID) FROM reports
group by report, topic, lat, lng, event
```