# Select values of a table with distinct values of a specific field of that table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, distinct

Suppose this DB table:

```
DECLARE @SUBSTITUTE TABLE(SUBSTITUTECODE varchar(25), COLORCODE varchar(15), SIZEPOS smallint);

INSERT INTO @SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTECODE, COLORCODE, SIZEPOS) VALUES
('002252200005001', 'BLK', 2),
('002252200005002', 'BLK', 3),
('002252200005004', 'BLK', 5),
('002252200005005', 'BLK', 6),
('002252200005006', 'BLK', 10),
('002252200005007', 'BLK', 11),
('0022522005003', 'BLK', 4),
('0022522005004', 'BLK', 5);
```

I want to get all `SUBSTITUTECODE`, `COLORCODE`, `SIZEPOS` where `SIZEPOS` is unique - taking the first iteration of each duplicate value.

| SUBSTITUTECODE | COLORCODE | SIZEPOS |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 002252200005001 | BLK | 2 |
| 002252200005002 | BLK | 3 |
| 002252200005004 | BLK | 5 |
| 002252200005005 | BLK | 6 |
| 002252200005006 | BLK | 10 |
| 002252200005007 | BLK | 11 |
| 0022522005003 | BLK | 4 |

The closest similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6300412/15576971) comes from MySQL

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Your data doesn't make sense to me.  Whence is the source of the value `MAY` which appears in the output?

Comment: Sorry, for the declaration of the table I used the abbreviation of Black color in English, but in the table I accidentally used the abbreviation of the color in another language! Correcting it now!

Comment: "taking the first iteration of each duplicate value." : First according to which order?!? Please remember that the table is SET of un-ordered rows and without `ORDER BY` the order is not guaranteed

Answer (score 0):

Please check if this solve your needs

```
DECLARE @SUBSTITUTE TABLE(SUBSTITUTECODE varchar(25), COLORCODE varchar(15), SIZEPOS smallint);

INSERT INTO @SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTECODE, COLORCODE, SIZEPOS) VALUES
('002252200005001', 'BLK', 2),
('002252200005002', 'BLK', 3),
('002252200005004', 'BLK', 5),
('002252200005005', 'BLK', 6),
('002252200005006', 'BLK', 10),
('002252200005007', 'BLK', 11),
('0022522005003', 'BLK', 4),
('0022522005004', 'BLK', 5);

;With MyCTE AS (
    SELECT SUBSTITUTECODE, COLORCODE, SIZEPOS
        , RN = row_number() over (partition by SIZEPOS order by SUBSTITUTECODE) -- I assume that "first" you mean when ordering by SUBSTITUTECODE
    FROM @SUBSTITUTE
)
SELECT SUBSTITUTECODE, COLORCODE, SIZEPOS
FROM MyCTE
WHERE RN = 1
```